# Does polarization remain?

Tags: electromagnetism

I understand that material gets polarized when an eletric field is applied to it which creates induces dipoles that create the bound charges, but when that electric field stops being applied, what happens to these dipoles? Does the material lose its polarization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the material you are considering. [Ferroelectric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferroelectricity) material, analogous to ferromagnetic materials for magnetism, can retain some or all of their electic polarisation after the applied field is removed. Most materials, however, will lose their polarisation when the field is removed.